# Extra empty lines when using visibility and toggle in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, visibility

I have this setup for my report, (Produkt = Product, Belopp = Amount)

[image: Design view]

---

I have set the properties for the Quarter & Months as following:

```
Hidden: True
InitialToggleState: False
ToggleItem: Quarter (for Months) & Year (for Quarter)
```

I am getting these extra lines which are placed were the expanded information (quarter & months) will be placed.
The result is the following:

[image: Extra line]
[image: Arrow that shows problem] Here you can see the space I need don´t want to be there...

As you can see I have also merged the cells under "Produkt" for nicer looks. This has no impact on the result.

Next view when expanding Quarter:
[image: Expanding quarter]

Next view when expanding Months:
[image: Expanding months]

Now, I would like to NOT see the extra space when open the report, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Which "extra" line? The one with "Feb, Jan, Mar"? Have you tried setting the `Hidden` property of that row?

Comment: The "extra line" is the line which is empty when starting the report. Ok, maybe call it empty space, between year and amount for produkt. I cannot make that row hidden because I cannot select it, if I select it, it will give me only the tablix properties..

Comment: Is this in preview or from report viewer? Also have you got **can shrink** = TRUE?

Comment: I get an empty space in preview but renders correctly in report viewer.

Comment: the "Can shrink" doesn´t work and also it doesn´t renders correctly in my extern report viewing program, thanks for proposal though.

Comment: Rather than toggling the visibility of the Quarter and Month textboxes, have the entire Row visibility toggled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not enough to simply set it in the properties. Need to do some more.

In Report Desiner, right-click on the tablix row, select "Row Visibility...", set to "When the report is initially run" to be "Hide", check "Display can be toggled by this report item" checkbox, select the name of your toggler text box in the drop down.

Same can be done to columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a conflict where multiple controls are all trying to set the visibility property on one or more cells within that row, and you're ending up with the space for the row being taken, but the content remaining hidden until the [+] is clicked.

Look into what is affecting the visibility of that row - via properties, grouping, or toggle items.

Comment: Well, no conflicts, I don´t think it´s possible to hide that rows (which contains the drilldown info, quarter & month), I have looked in a textbook were they have the same white space.. I found it a bit annoying..

Answer (score 0):

This would typically mean that you're using the hide and show from the properties box of the row... to remove the blank spaces you need to do it by right clicking on the row and selecting the tablix properties and changing the toggle item in the visibility section.